# Connecting to mysql database using IntelliJ

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a program to use a database for the first time. I've been following [this guide](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JDBC_Basic.html), but at step 3.1 I'd prefer not having to go trough the console each time I want to launch the program, so I started looking in to how to do it trough IntelliJ. [Jetbrains official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-mysql-database) (and all other sources I've found) says that I should go the Database tool window (View | Tool Windows | Database), however, [database does not appear as an option in that menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlemR.png).

I'm trying to run the following code

```
public class JdbcSelectTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookshop?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC",
                        "stefan", "xxxx");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()
                ) {
            String strSelect = "select title, price, qty from books";
            System.out.println("The SQL statement is: " + strSelect + "\n");

            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);
            System.out.println("The records selected are:");
            int rowCount = 0;
            while (rset.next()) {
                String title = rset.getString("title");
                double price = rset.getDouble("price");
                int qty = rset.getInt("qty");
                System.out.println(title + ", " + price + ", " + qty);
                ++rowCount;
            }
            System.out.println("Total number of records = " +  rowCount);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in this error:

```
C:\Users\Stefan\.jdks\openjdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:N:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=59866:N:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Stefan\IdeaProjects\SQL select\out\production\SQL select" JdbcSelectTest
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookshop?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at JdbcSelectTest.main(JdbcSelectTest.java:6)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Do you have MySQL JDBC jar added to the module dependencies? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency.

Comment: That did it, thank you!